# The function f is defined as follows: $f:A \to A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function f is defined as follows:$f:A$ to $A$ where$$ f(x)=\frac{3(x +1)}{x^2-1}$$
Along my proof in showing that  show that there
exists an x ∈ A with $f(x) = y$  (showing f is onto) ,I ran into a snag in  conducting algebric calucations. My work is as follows:$$y=\frac{3(x +1)}{x^2-1}$$ $$y(x^2-1)=(x+1)$$$$x^2y-y=3x+3$$$$x^2y+3x=y+3$$ $$x(xy+3)=y+3$$$$x=\frac {y+3}{xy+3} $$

> With the use of an online calculator it showed that $x=\frac {y+3}{y} $.
>   Where in my algebric calculations did i go wrong?Assuming that $x=\frac {y+3}{y} $ is the correct answer

Comment: Which set is $A$?

Comment: Hint: $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: @ajotatxe The set doesnt really matter, i was just concerned with the algebraic calculation not the entire solving of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

One of mistakes is that you've lost minus $x^2y-3x=y+3$. Anyway it's not the real matter. The thing is that you have to leave x alone, while you have x in the both sides. Use in the beginning hint $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ or otherwise solve the quadratic for x which would be not very smart.

Comment: lol thank you, as simple as it was i found my mistake.